# Eclipse IDE won't include <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h>

Tags: c, eclipse, xcode, macos, null

Eclipse IDE on MacbookPro using (Xcode) won't include stdio.h and stdlib.h

the message given is "Unresolved inclusion: stdlib.h" and "Unresolved inclusion: "

As a result the program is not running "NULL"

I my macbook recently updated Xcode and since the update, Eclipse has not been running the same. I have tried to solve the issue using the methods provided for others but nothing has worked.

I am wondering if this has to do something with my computer updating Xcode app. None of the libraries are working for my programs.

Comment: Have you re-installed the command line tools?
Sometimes Xcode removes them when updating and they must be re-installed.
I believe the latest tools are [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.10_for_Xcode_7.dmg).

Comment: I am no exaclty sure how to re-install the comand line tools

Comment: I provided a link to them on my last comment, give that a download and open the file...

Comment: I get a window that says only developers are allowed to view the webpage.

Comment: This helped On OS X you may need to manually install the command line developer tools (which first requires installing Xcode) using the command /usr/bin/xcode-select --install and then you'll be able to point Eclipse at /usr/include/ –  RobV Apr 15 '14 at 22:24

Comment: There you go - so it was the command line tools after all. Good that you figured it out!

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of the old paths. Although it now works, I still keep getting warnings that say, "Invalid project path: Include path not found"